# How do I access the upcdatabase.org API?

Tags: xml, json, web-services, barcode

I'm working on a Java project that accepts a UPC barcode and searches online for a product description.

I'm trying to access the upcdatabase.org API. The site instructs you to use the following URL for a JSON response with the product information:

format: upcdatabase.org/api/json/APIKEY/BARCODE

for example: http://upcdatabase.org/api/json/2316e70001a2757dc55dc64ce0465787/0111222333446

This works great for their test product, but doesn't work with any of the real barcodes I've given it. I get this when I try a real product: {"valid":"false","reason":"Code not found in database."}

However, when I enter the same barcode into the text box on their web interface, it finds the product just fine.

They mention that they moved their API service to api.upcdatabase.org but do not provide any documentation for how to access this site.

Is anyone familiar with this site's API that might now what's going on?

Here are some of the barcodes I've tried so far:
016000275164
031200016058
024100440689

Comment: Just curious if you're still using upcdatabase.org. It currently seems to be down, I haven't been able to find any info about whether it will be going back up. Getting complaints from users of my app because my app relies on it.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I was using it for a class project early this year. I actually pinged 4 different UPC databases and combined the results so I could avoid that problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the UPC database API wants all UPC codes to be padded to 13 digits, with leading zeros if necessary. So your example code of

024100440689

...needs to be padded out to:

0024100440689

Take a look at what you get from making a request to http://upcdatabase.org/api/json/2316e70001a2757dc55dc64ce0465787/0024100440689

Comment: Just an update: I emailed the admin and got this response: "I just changed the way code searches are handled. Before, the way a code search on the main site was different to the way it was handled via the API.

The API should no longer care if the item is padded with 0's or not."